# Testing failing to resolve to a type with all imports

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, junit4, fileinputstream

"File" is underlined with swiggly lines. How would I fix this?
I am really confused since I have the correct imports don't I? Tried searching for answers online and couldn't find it.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.junit.Test;


@Test
    public void testLogin() {
        System.setIn(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")));
    }


}
```

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `o` on eclipse will do the trick

Comment: Now, the whole line area from "new" is underlined in red.

Comment: READ the error, its probably telling  you to surround the line with `try-catch` or declare the method to use `throws`.